# Xamarin - Shared Class Library Accessing System.IO.File

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, xamarin.mac

I try to create a really simple app containing

- Windows Version
- Mac Version
- Portable Class Library

I would like to put the code (as much as possible) into the Portable Class Library.
Now i simply want to check if a file exists using `System.IO.File.Exists()` but the `File` object is not available. I tryed to target different plattforms but i cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.IO.File` is not available in the PCL code. You will need to implement in platform specific code. You will also need to verify that it exists for each platform. I know it does for Android and iOS, have never tried using it on Mac and Windows. Although from Xamarin's [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/application_fundamentals/databases/#Initializing_the_Database) it looks like at least Mac does have `System.IO.File`.

Once you have methods in each platform project, you can reference the platform specific method from your PCL code using Xamarin's [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/).

Answer (score 2):

What [@hvaughan3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3850012/hvaughan3) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208063/xamarin-shared-class-library-accessing-system-io-file/38208170#38208170) is correct in that the `System.IO.File` is not available from your PCL and it needs to be implemented within each platform and *injected* into your PCL. That said the good news is that like many of these *common* requirements there already is a plugin to do that so you don't need to do it yourself.

Have a look at the following [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/simple-cross-platform-file-io-for-ios-android-and-windows/) that describes how to use the [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) plugin within your PCL project.